# How to enable extension loading in SQLite3?

Tags: php, sqlite, sqlite-json1

I want to play with the [JSON1](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) extension for SQLite3 but when I do the following;

```
<?php
$db = new SQLite3('foo.db');
$db->loadExtension('json1.dll');
?>
```

I get the error;

```
Warning: SQLite3::loadExtension(): Unable to load extension at 'ext\json1.dll' in C:\test\json1.php on line 3
```

The [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#load_extension) says that extension loading is disabled by default for security reasons but can be enabled by a prior call to the C interface function [sqlite3_enable_load_extension()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/enable_load_extension.html).

How can I call that function, or is there another way to enable SQLite extension loading from PHP?

PS. I compiled `json1.dll` using MinGW+Msys by doing;

```
gcc -g -shared json1.c sqlite3ext.h -o json1.dll
```